# Best players' typical Hanabi scores

Tags: computer-ai, skill, hanabi

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanabi_(card_game)#AI_challenge), the best computer programs consistently achieve perfect scores in five-player vanilla *Hanabi*, averaging almost 25 points per game when each player uses the same algorithm. But I can't find any resources on the best average scores achieved by humans or computers with a different number of players, or with a variant like rainbow or six suits, or allowing empty clues. Is any of this information published somewhere?

Comment: If you are interested in algorithms that play Hanabi, I suggest to look at papers that cite the paper: "The Hanabi Challenge: A New Frontier for AI Research" (2019) and have the word Hanabi in them.   see 
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0%2C5&cites=10258230482856565196&scipsc=1&q=Hanabi&btnG=

Comment: Also this: https://github.com/hanabi/hanabi.github.io/tree/87cbb89911cf5bafb2f06cdebd0fdd6d4135c52b/academic_papers